# ASP.NET User Control Inside ListView Edit Template

Tags: listview, user-controls

I have User Controls (.ascx) file and when I place it inside a ListView Edit Template it throws a NullReference error (Object reference not set to an instance of an object).

Why? Is it because of a late binding?

Comment: Is there something wrong with your keyboard?  Getting used to that new DVORAK layout?

Comment: <%@ Register src="UserControls/UcMemberLookup.ascx" tagname="UcMemberLookup" tagprefix="uc6" %>

<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ods1" DataKeyNames="Id"> 
 <EditItemTemplate>
 <uc3:UcMemberLookup ID="UcMemberLookup1" runat="server" MemberId='<%# Bind("MemberId") %>' />
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

The UserControl throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the error. It was a "User Error". The Paramter MemberId was null. So I changed the Property  `public int MemberId{set;get;}` to `public int?  MemberId{set;get;}`. That fixed the issue.